# teensy pointer on input string

Tags: pointers, arduino

Currently a student in college, decided to jump ahead of my programming class and have a little fun with pointers.  This is supposed to take a specific serial input and change the state of three LED's I have attached to the Teensy++2.0.  However it seems to be just giving me back the first input.
http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytesUntil
This is my reference for the ReadBytesUntil()  The input goes #,#,### (1,1,255 being an example)
I guess basically my question is, does ReadBytesUntil() deal with commas?  And if so, whats going on here?

EDIT -- I asked my teacher and even he has no clue why it doesn't work.

```
char *dataFinder(char *str){
  while (*str != ','){
    str++;
  }
  str++;
  return str;
}

void inputDecoder(){
  str = incomingText;
  whichLED = *str;
  dataFinder(str);
  onoff = *str;
  dataFinder(str);
  powerLevel = *str;
}



void loop(){
  int length;
  if (Serial.available() > 0 ){      //this is basically: if something is typed in, do       something.
length = Serial.readBytesUntil(13,incomingText, 10);  //reads what is typed in, and stores it in incomingVar
incomingText[length]=0;  ///swapping out cr with null 
inputDecoder();
//ledControl();
Serial.print("Entered:");
//incomingText[9]=0;
Serial.println(incomingText);  //Here for testing, to show what values I'm getting back.
Serial.println(whichLED);
Serial.println(onoff);
Serial.println(powerLevel);
}
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I apologize if this is really stupid.  This is my first post here.

Comment: What is the output?  `whichLED`, `onoff`, and `powerLevel` should be "1,1,255", "1, 255", "255" respectively because `dataFinder()` is not NUL terminating any of the strings. EDIT: You are not using the return value from `dataFinder()` so `str` always has the same value in `inputDecoder()`, try doing `str = dataFinder(str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str` in `inputDecoder()` is from the global scope and is not the same `str` in `dataFinder()`, which has local scope.

Imagine this ASCII picture is the layout of memory:

```
  str
+-----+-----+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  *  |     |     |     | ... |  1  |  ,  |  1  |  ,  |  2  |  5  |  5  | \n  |
+--|--+-----+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   | 
   |
   \-----------------------------^
```

When you pass `str` to `dataFinder()` it creates a copy of the pointer, which I'll call `str'`

```
  str         str'
+-----+-----+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  *  |     |  *  |     | ... |  1  |  ,  |  1  |  ,  |  2  |  5  |  5  | \n  |
+--|--+-----+--|--+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |           \-----------------^
   |
   \-----------------------------^
```

When `dataFinder()` increments `str` it is really altering `str'`

```
  str         str'
+-----+-----+-----+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  *  |     |  *  |     | ... |  1  |  ,  |  1  |  ,  |  2  |  5  |  5  | \n  |
+--|--+-----+--|--+-----+     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |           \-----------------------------^
   |
   \-----------------------------^
```

Then, when you return to `inputDecoder()` you dereference `str` which is still pointing at the start of the string.

You can either assign the value of `str'` back to the global `str` using:

```
str = dataFinder(str);
```

or change `dataFinder()` so it does not take an argument, therefore not copying the variable.

Comment: Awesome.  This seems to fix it.  It doesn't like my three digit code at the end, but I can make math to figure that out.  Thanks a ton dude!